# Form submit not working in Webkit Playwright

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, automated-tests, playwright

I have a simple login page that I am trying to test with Playwright.

```
<form method="POST" name="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="captcha_response">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="token">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" value="" type="text" maxlength="100" name="username" class="form-control" autofocus autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="username" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" maxlength="100" name="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group flex flex-col-reverse md:flex-row flex-wrap justify-between items-center">
        <div>
            <p class="text-gray-600 text-sm">
                Forgot your <a href="http://localhost:7013/forgot-username" class="text-gray-600 text-sm">username</a> or <a href="http://localhost:7013/forgot-password" class="text-gray-600 text-sm">password</a>?
            </p>
        </div>
        <button name="loginButton"  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-full md:w-auto mb-3 md:mb-0">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have written a simply test to complete the login form, which redirects you to the dashboard.

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test'

test("Ans portal login page", async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('/login', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });
    console.log(page.url())
    // Wait for the page to load


    await page.click('input[id="username"]')
    await page.fill('#username', 'test')

    await page.click('input[id="password"]')
    await page.fill('#password', '12345')

    const submitButton = await page.locator('button[name="loginButton"]')
    console.log('button', await submitButton.innerText())
    await expect(submitButton).toHaveCount(1)
    await submitButton.click({force: true})

    await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle')
    console.log('url', page.url())
    await expect(page).toHaveURL('/dashboard')
    await expect(page.locator('h1#page_title')).toHaveText('Good afternoon Alan');
});
```

This works fine in chromium and firefox, but fails in webkit.
After the button click, the page url is still login and not dashboard.

This is being done on Ubunut (via 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2) using node v16.16.0

Sample output

```
Running 3 tests using 1 worker

  ✓  1 [chromium] › tests/auth.spec.ts:3:1 › Login page (12s)
http://localhost:7013/login
button Login
url http://localhost:7013/dashboard
  ✓  2 [firefox] › tests/auth.spec.ts:3:1 › Login page (15s)
http://localhost:7013/login
button Login
url http://localhost:7013/dashboard
  ✘  3 [webkit] › tests/auth.spec.ts:3:1 › Login page (8s)
http://localhost:7013/login
button Login
url http://localhost:7013/login


  1) [webkit] › tests/auth.spec.ts:3:1 › Login page ================================================

    Error: expect(received).toHaveURL(expected)

    Expected string: "http://localhost:7013/dashboard"
    Received string: "http://localhost:7013/login"
    Call log:
      - expect.toHaveURL with timeout 5000ms
      - waiting for selector ":root"
      -   selector resolved to <html lang="en">…</html>
      -   unexpected value "http://localhost:7013/login"
      -   selector resolved to <html lang="en">…</html>
      -   unexpected value "http://localhost:7013/login"
      -   selector resolved to <html lang="en">…</html>
      -   unexpected value "http://localhost:7013/login"
      -   selector resolved to <html lang="en">…</html>
      -   unexpected value "http://localhost:7013/login"
      -   selector resolved to <html lang="en">…</html>
      -   unexpected value "http://localhost:7013/login"
      -   selector resolved to <html lang="en">…</html>
      -   unexpected value "http://localhost:7013/login"
      -   selector resolved to <html lang="en">…</html>
      -   unexpected value "http://localhost:7013/login"
      -   selector resolved to <html lang="en">…</html>
      -   unexpected value "http://localhost:7013/login"


      20 |     await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle')
      21 |     console.log('url', page.url())
    > 22 |     await expect(page).toHaveURL('/dashboard')
         |                        ^
      23 |     await expect(page.locator('h1#page_title')).toHaveText('Good afternoon Alan');
      24 | });
      25 |

        at /home/projects/playwright/tests/auth.spec.ts:22:24

    attachment #1: video (video/webm) --------------------------------------------------------------
    test-results/tests-auth-Login-page-webkit/video.webm
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    attachment #2: screenshot (image/png) ----------------------------------------------------------
    test-results/tests-auth-Login-page-webkit/test-failed-1.png
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  1 failed
    [webkit] › tests/auth.spec.ts:3:1 › Login page =================================================
  2 passed (40s)
```

Comment: I couldn't replicate your example in my environment, can you upload your application's code (only the login and redirection part to /dashboard) to Codesandbox (or other in cloud simulator)?

Comment: Are you using a SPA (Single Page Application), or a static page?

Comment: @LucasPaixão it is just a standard Laravel setup, so a 302 redirect on login

Comment: What does the playwright report video show?

Comment: The webkit is reporting TLS handshake errors

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete response since without more context I'm having a hard time being certain of what's going on but could you try replacing

```js
await submitButton.click({force: true})
await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle')
await expect(page).toHaveURL('/dashboard')
```

with

```js
await submitButton.click({force: true})
await page.waitForUrl('/dashboard', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'})
```

The reasoning for that suggestion is that I'm worried by the time the `waitForLoadState` function is called, navigation hasn't even started yet (I find webkit to always be the slowest with playwright) thus it is already true.

*This is not a complete answer because you still have a 5000ms timeout and I don't think your navigation should be taking this long, though being able to see the test-results/tests-auth-Login-page-webkit/video.webm video from `npm playwright-report` would probably help figuring it out.*

Comment: not working for me. I get `TypeError: page.waitForUrl is not a function`.  
I'm using Playwright 1.27.1

Comment: That's very odd, it was added in 1.11 https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-url

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
await page.goto('/login', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' })
```

With looking for the selector you expect on the page:

```
await page.goto('/login')
await page.waitForSelector('input[id="username"]')
```

Comment: Not fixing webkit